# Android: Retain Variables In UI Fragment through Config Changes

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I want to retain temporary variables through config changes (rotation) in a UI fragment.  I've read that in general you shouldn't use setRetainInstance(true) on a UI fragment.  What are my options here?  Do I have to resort to using a non ui child fragment with setRetainInstance(true) attached to my fragment?  Id like to avoid that if possible, child fragments can be frustrating.

Also, I'd really prefer to keep the fragments variables encapsulated inside the fragment itself.  I could store the data in another non-ui fragment attached to the activity but I'd prefer not to.  Seems like there should be an easier way to do this.  I wish fragments had something like onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() as a fallback.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `android:configChanges="orientation"` option the housing activity in your manifest.  This will cause all orientation changes to call `onConfigurationChanged()` as opposed to `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

I've never read about not using setRetainInstanceState in an UI fragment. One of the big advantages of fragments is that you CAN retain the state through config changes, just by using that flag. I use it in all my apps. Just give it a go :)

Also, child fragment's can't retain their instance state.

Comment: `setRetainInstance` cannot be used if your Fragment is on the back stack as per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

Comment: I'm not sure in what situation that takes effect. I add fragments to the backstack all the time, and they all have setRetainInstance(true).

Comment: I've been looking on the internet for the past 2 hours.  Found numerous references hinting that you shouldn't use retaininstance with UI fragments, but nothing really official except for the note from google saying not to use them with the backstack.  the main concern seems to be memory leaks and backstack.